# Unable to run RMI client on different machine

Tags: java, rmi, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to run RMI client on a remote machine in my LAN.
I have implemented Server and Registry on a different machine in LAN.
It works fine on same machine. But when I try to run Client program on different machine it shows following exception:
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CalculatorImpl_Stub (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried googling "no security manager: RMI class loader disabled"?

Comment: @Augusto That's a red herring. The actual issue here is the actual exception and why it occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't distributed the stub file to the client.